# Issues With Merged Columns in Table

Tags: tables, longtable, multicolumn

I have created a code for the table below.
My issue is that the columns with the `Var(\alpha^m)/Var(\alpha)` are messing all the layout of the second part of the table "Percentage of Total Variation Explained By:"

Do you know how to solve that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}[c]{lccccccc}
    \caption{Variability of Asset Demands}
    \label{my-label}\\
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$~\gamma =5, \psi = 1, \rho =0.92^{1/4}  $}} \\
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \endhead
    \toprule
    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Var($\alpha^m$)/Var($\alpha$)(\%)}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Var($\alpha^h$)/Var($\alpha$)(\%)}}
    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Cov($\alpha^m$,$\alpha^h$)/Var($\alpha$)(\%)}}\\
    %
    \toprule
    ~~Stock & 71.33 & 71.33 & 71.33 \\
    ~~Bond & 71.33 & 71.33 & 71.33 \\
     \toprule
     \multicolumn{7}{l}{Percentage of Total Variation Explained By:} \\  
     \\
    ~~Stock  \\
    &&{$rtb_t$} & {$xr_t$ } & {$xb_t$} &{$y_t$} & {$(d-p)_t$} & {$spr_t$} \\
    &$rtb_t$  &0.0254  &   0.0045 &   -0.0037 &    0.0710  &   0.0425  &   0.0014\\
    &$xr_t$  && 0.0055  &  -0.0012  &   0.0142 &    0.0130  &   0.0005 \\
    &$xb_t$   && & 0.0009  &  -0.0116 &   -0.0078  &  -0.0002\\
    &$y_t$  & && & 0.2177  &   0.1336  &   0.0041 \\
    &$(d-p)_t$  && & & & 0.2374 &   -0.0042\\
    &$spr_t$ &&&&&&0.0008 \\
    ~~Bond   \\
    &&{$rtb_t$} & {$xr_t$ } & {$xb_t$} &{$y_t$} & {$(d-p)_t$} & {$spr_t$} \\
    &$rtb_t$  & 0.0143  &   0.0088 &    0.0073 &    0.1078 &   -0.0147 &   -0.0148\\
    &$xr_t$  &&0.0370   &  0.0079  &   0.0748 &   -0.0156   & -0.0188\\
    &$xb_t$   && &0.0062 &    0.0614   & -0.0095  &  -0.0058\\
    &$y_t$  & &&   &   0.8936  &  -0.1250  &  -0.1207\\
    &$(d-p)_t$  && & & & 0.0507  &  -0.0278\\
    &$spr_t$ &&&&&&0.1679 \\
 \bottomrule                 

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

It should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the documentclass and relevant packages in order to make a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? It would also help if you describe your desired layout (maybe with a sketch) as at least I am not able to see from the code, how you want your table to look like.

Comment: Maybe you could use `\multicolumn{2}` for the 'Var...' row and the two following rows.

Comment: @leandriis I just added what you suggested

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Do you really need the `longtable` environment for your table? As it is now, it should fit onto a single page, but it is wider than the textwidth of an `article` page. Would rotating the table to fit onto a landscape page be fine for you?

Comment: @leandriis I would actually like to let it fit in one page vertically, but I was not able to so in my paper I needed to put it horizontally with landscape. If you are able to put it vertically this would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

Your table really consists of two separate subtables which are only loosely (if at all) connected. If you want to keep the single `longtable` setup, I suggest you  use two (logical) columns for the numeric information in the upper part. I'd also suggest aligning the numbers in the lower part on their respective decimal markers. Oh, and use `\bm`, not `\textbf`, to render math material in bold.

[image]

A closing comment: It's not clear to me why you'd want to use a `longtable` environment for this material. Nesting a couple of `tabular` environments inside a `table` environment would seem more straightforward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,bm,siunitx}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}
\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4.5pt}

\begin{longtable}{@{} c *{6}{S[table-format=-1.4]} @{}}
\caption{Variability of Asset Demands}
\label{my-label}\\
\toprule
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{$\bm{\gamma =5,\ \psi = 1,\ \rho =0.92^{1/4}  }$} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\toprule
\endhead

\bottomrule  
\endlastfoot

&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\bm{\Var(\alpha^m)/\Var(\alpha)}$}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\bm{\Var(\alpha^h)/\Var(\alpha)}$}
&\multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{$\bm{\Cov(\alpha^m,\alpha^h)/\Var(\alpha)}$} \\[0.5ex]
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\%)} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\%)} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{(\%)} \\
%
\midrule
Stock & \multicolumn{2}{c}{71.33} 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{71.33} 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{71.33} \\
Bond  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{71.33} 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{71.33} 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{71.33} \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{Percentage of Total Variation Explained By:} \\[1ex]
Stock  \\
    &{$rtb_t$} & {$xr_t$ } & {$xb_t$} &{$y_t$} & {$(d-p)_t$} & {$spr_t$} \\
    {$rtb_t$}  &0.0254  &   0.0045 &   -0.0037 &    0.0710  &   0.0425  &   0.0014\\
    {$xr_t$}  && 0.0055  &  -0.0012  &   0.0142 &    0.0130  &   0.0005 \\
    {$xb_t$}   && & 0.0009  &  -0.0116 &   -0.0078  &  -0.0002\\
    {$y_t$}  & && & 0.2177  &   0.1336  &   0.0041 \\
    {$(d-p)_t$}  && & & & 0.2374 &   -0.0042\\
    {$spr_t$} &&&&&&0.0008 \\[3ex]

Bond   \\
    &{$rtb_t$} & {$xr_t$ } & {$xb_t$} &{$y_t$} & {$(d-p)_t$} & {$spr_t$} \\
    {$rtb_t$}  & 0.0143  &   0.0088 &    0.0073 &    0.1078 &   -0.0147 &   -0.0148\\
    {$xr_t$}  &&0.0370   &  0.0079  &   0.0748 &   -0.0156   & -0.0188\\
    {$xb_t$}   && &0.0062 &    0.0614   & -0.0095  &  -0.0058\\
    {$y_t$}  & &&   &   0.8936  &  -0.1250  &  -0.1207\\
    {$(d-p)_t$}  && & & & 0.0507  &  -0.0278\\
    {$spr_t$} &&&&&&0.1679 \\               
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different approach using two separate `tabular*` environments  for the upper and the lower part. Both `tabular*`  environments share the same width (`\textwidth`) to ensure equal widths of the horizontal rules (Suggested by [Mico in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438650/issues-with-merged-columns-in-table/438662#comment1101323_438662)). For the alignment of numbers relative to their decimal separator, I have used `S` type columns from the `siunitx` package. I have also added the `threeparttable` environment and `tablenotes` to allow for notes under the table as shown in the image in the question. To make sure that the table fits into the textwidth, I have slightly decreased the `tabcolsep`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Variability of Asset Demands}
  \label{my-label}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
 % \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}

    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l*3{S[table-format=2.2]}}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{4}{c}{$\bm{\gamma =5,\ \psi = 1,\ \rho =0.92^{1/4}  }$}\\
      \midrule
      &{$\bm{\Var(\alpha^m)/\Var(\alpha)}$}& {$\bm{\Var(\alpha^h)/\Var(\alpha)}$}  &{$\bm{\Cov(\alpha^m,\alpha^h)/\Var(\alpha)}$}\\
      & {(\%)} & {(\%)} & {(\%)} \\
      \cmidrule(rl){2-2} \cmidrule(rl){3-3} \cmidrule(rl){4-4} 
      Stock  & 71.33 & 71.33 & 71.33\\
      Bond  & 71.33 & 71.33 & 71.33\\
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{5ex}}r*2{S[table-format=1.4]}*4{S[table-format=-1.4]}}
     \midrule
     \multicolumn{7}{c}{Percentage of Total Variation Explained By:}\\
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{Stock}   \\
      &{$rtb_t$} & {$xr_t$ } & {$xb_t$} &{$y_t$} & {$(d-p)_t$} & {$spr_t$} \\
      $rtb_t$  &0.0254  &   0.0045 &   -0.0037 &    0.0710  &   0.0425  &   0.0014\\
      $xr_t$  && 0.0055  &  -0.0012  &   0.0142 &    0.0130  &   0.0005 \\
      $xb_t$   && & 0.0009  &  -0.0116 &   -0.0078  &  -0.0002\\
      $y_t$  & && & 0.2177  &   0.1336  &   0.0041 \\
      $(d-p)_t$  && & & & 0.2374 &   -0.0042\\
      $spr_t$ &&&&&&0.0008 \\ 
      \addlinespace
      \multicolumn{1}{@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}l}{Bond}   \\
      &{$rtb_t$} & {$xr_t$ } & {$xb_t$} &{$y_t$} & {$(d-p)_t$} & {$spr_t$} \\
      $rtb_t$  & 0.0143  &   0.0088 &    0.0073 &    0.1078 &   -0.0147 &   -0.0148\\
      $xr_t$  &&0.0370   &  0.0079  &   0.0748 &   -0.0156   & -0.0188\\
      $xb_t$   && &0.0062 &    0.0614   & -0.0095  &  -0.0058\\
      $y_t$  & &&   &   0.8936  &  -0.1250  &  -0.1207\\
      $(d-p)_t$  && & & & 0.0507  &  -0.0278\\
      $spr_t$ &&&&&&0.1679 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
 % \end{tabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[] \textbf{Note:} Here can be the table notes
  \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I would recommend getting rid of the "outer" `tabular` though, and placing `\multicolumn{4}{c}{$\bm{\gamma =5,\ \psi = 1,\ \rho =0.92^{1/4}  }$}` in the first "inner" `tabular`. To guarantee that the two "real" tabular environments have the same overall width, switch them to `tabular*` environments a common width setting (most likely, `\textwidth`).

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for your suggestion that is indeed a lot easier than nested tabulars. I have edited my answer accordingly.